# jquery mouseover and mouseleave do not working

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave

I wrote a simple jquery function but not working. If you guys find out what is the issue you really made my day happy.

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("col-md-4").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").stop().transition({ scale: 1.05 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".baslik").stop().css({ "color": "#b19460" });
    $(this).find(".golge").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.65 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".bordur").stop().fadeTo(600, 1 );

 });
 $("col-md-4").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find("img").stop().transition({ scale: 1 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".baslik").stop().css({ "color": "#fff" });
    $(this).find(".golge").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.15 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".bordur").stop().fadeTo(600, 0 );
});
```

});

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y66WM/1/

Comment: select the class with `.`

Comment: @user48641 You forget to add Jquery File Please see my answer

Comment: @user48641 check transition effect having some problem.. rest working.. http://jsfiddle.net/Y66WM/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add **"."** selector
Use This code

```
$(".col-md-4").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").stop().transition({ scale: 1.05 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".baslik").stop().css({ "color": "#b19460" });
    $(this).find(".golge").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.65 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".bordur").stop().fadeTo(600, 1 );

 });
 $(".col-md-4").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find("img").stop().transition({ scale: 1 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".baslik").stop().css({ "color": "#fff" });
    $(this).find(".golge").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.15 }, 600);
    $(this).find(".bordur").stop().fadeTo(600, 0 );
});
```

You got this error in your page

[image]

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y66WM/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.` (dot) for *class* in [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

*Change*

```
$("col-md-4").mouseover(function() {
```

*To*

```
$(".col-md-4").mouseover(function() {
```

Comment: These events are getting fired, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Y66WM/5/

Answer (score 1):

syntax error in selector  use `class .` selector or `id #` **[selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

```
 $(".col-md-4")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the class or id for `$("col-md-4");`

May be it `$(".col-md-4")` or `$("#col-md-4")`